# Looking for convenient way to paste a region of Excel cell data into MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, excel

I have data in my Excel file, I would like to view and edit the tables visually. 
The resulting cells should be pasted into MySQL.
What is the way to do that?

Comment: Save the Excel file in CSV format, then use [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html) or [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can Create update or insert statements as column in your excel and past the resulting script into your Favourite MySql Query tool

Its not Quick to setup the first cell but the rest is easy and you can reuse the formula next time you have the same data set

Comment: Just be careful to properly escape string literals, etc.

Comment: I am not sure as og what you meant... "create, update or insert as column"? resulting script? Can you please explain?

Comment: You can create concatenated strings to fill the data of a update statement for example ,assuming your data has a header then this could be a cell in row Two's content  =" update sales set amount = "&B2&" where product_id = "&A2";"  and then you excel copy it down to the end of your data,i personally use the last column after the data  ,string fields need to be escaped